# Matplotlib y axis scale not fitting values

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I plot the probability mass function of a binomial distribution with:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
binom=[scs.binom.pmf(k,100,0.2) for k in range(100)]
print(np.max(binom)) #0.0993002148088
[plt.axvline(k,ymax=scs.binom.pmf(k,100,0.2)) for k in range(100)]
plt.ylim(ymax=0.1)

plt.show()
```

As you see the maximum value of binom is 0.099300 means the plot should nearly reach the upper limit of the y-axis but the result is as follows:

[image]

So what am I doing wrong? Why is the graph not fitting to the limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may want to use a [`stem` plot](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20stem#matplotlib.pyplot.stem).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as scs

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
binom=[scs.binom.pmf(k,100,0.2) for k in range(100)]

# Scale the yvalues by ymax
plt.stem(binom, linefmt='b-', markerfmt='none', basefmt='none')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`axvline`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline) accepts values in the range 0 to 1 for `ymax` (i.e. it is in axes coordinates, not data coordinates). From the docs:

> `ymax` : scalar, optional, default: 1
>
> Should be between 0 and 1, 0 being the bottom of the plot, 1 the top of the plot.

So, you are telling it to only plot around 0.1 of the way up the axes. If you wish to stick with using `axvline` to make the plot, you will need to scale the values before you plot them.

e.g.

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
binom=[scs.binom.pmf(k,100,0.2) for k in range(100)]
print(np.max(binom)) #0.0993002148088
# Set ymax here
ymax = 0.1
# Scale the yvalues by ymax
[plt.axvline(k,ymax=scs.binom.pmf(k,100,0.2)/ymax) for k in range(100)]
# Use ymax again here
plt.ylim(ymax=ymax)

plt.show()
```

Alternatively, you might want to look into using `plt.bar` to make this plot; for example:

```
plt.bar(range(len(binom)), binom)
```

Comment: Ok but this is not very convenient if I had to re-scale the ymax value each time. So how could I solve it by using plt.bar()?

Comment: something like: `plt.bar(range(len(binom), binom)` should do it